# Why connecting to remote server using Sequelize uses local machie IP as target DB server IP?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm mounting an API in Google Cloud Run that connects to an MySQL DB server using Sequelize.

This is the standard setup:

index.js file

```
const DB_CONFIG = require('../db/db.config');

const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
let sequelize = new Sequelize(
    DB_CONFIG.NAME,
    DB_CONFIG.USER,
    DB_CONFIG.PASSWORD,
    { host: DB_CONFIG.HOST, dialect: DB_CONFIG.DIALECT, pool: DB_CONFIG.POOL }
)
```

db.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  NAME: process.env.DB_NAME,
  HOST: process.env.DB_HOST,
  USER: process.env.DB_USER,
  PASSWORD: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  DIALECT: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
  POOL: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
};
```

The problem comes when I start the project, it fails with an error that shows it is trying to connect to the same IP as the local machine public IP:

```
{
    code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
    errno: 1045,
    sqlState: '28000',
    sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'DB_USER'@'LOCAL_MACHINE_IP' (using password: YES)",
    sql: undefined
  }
```

The problem happens either if I write the final values directly in the db.config file or the values are read from *process.env*.

It is important to not that I'm using the Google Cloud Secret Manager to inject this values to process.env.

Also, the execution logs in Google Cloud Run shows that the API is trying to connect using the local IP.

What could be happening, and how can I search the cause of this error?

Comment: What's the value of `process.env.DB_HOST`? Where do you read the `.env` file? [ask]: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.**

Comment: This is an invalid credentials error, and actually indicates your client made a good TCP connection

Comment: Ok, I edited the post, adding the text error and clarifying about env information. (thanks @jabaa).

Comment: @trognanders, you are right. Recently, the Server Admin added another DB to the same server and modified the user to allow access to both of them. But with the same credentials. Do I need to respond to this change with another configuration or so?

Comment: It's unclear to me what problem you have. Are the values in `process.env.DB_HOST` as expected? If not, where do they come from? If they are correct, what is your question? Can you log `DB_CONFIG.HOST`? Is the value correct?

Comment: Yes, all the values from *process.env* are correct. This was verified.

Comment: What's your question? Can you log in with the CLI and these credentials? It looks like the problem is that the credentials are wrong or the user doesn't have the necessary permissions.

Comment: I will discuss this with the DBA, as @shadow has demonstrated, what I thought was an error indication in the code, was actually revealing wrong credentials or something alike. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: @mbastidasluis permissions in MySQL are really quirky, and honestly it is probably a configuration issue there. If you have a DBA, now is a reasonable time to loop them in.

Comment: That was the case. Thanks again you all for the time and excuse me for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with that IP address as the host name in a mysql user account indicates the client you are connecting **from**, not the mysql server's IP address you are connecting to.

See mysql manual on [account names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html) for details.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this is progress. Recently, the Server Admin added another DB (test db) and modified the user's permissions to allow it to connect to both DBs. But using the same credentials. Would it be possible that I need to adjust the code in some way to respond to this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you need to discuss this with your DBA as this is not a programming question! You need to use valid mysql user name and password combination in your application, but we cannot tell you what those should be.

Comment: Thank you all for your time.